# Change display format of found result of awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a `data.csv` file, its content:

```
0,H,"First Job"
0,M,"Second Job"
0,L,"Third Job"
...
```

in which the user can search its term on the 3rd column like below:
**./find.sh Third**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

awk -F"," -v findit="$1" '$3 ~ findit' data.csv
```

I want to change the displaying format of the result of `awk` to show the line of result, like this:

```
3 | 0 | L | "Third Job"
```

number **3** indicates that the result were found on the 3rd line.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v findit="$1" 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=" | "} $3~findit{$1=$1;print FNR,$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simple explanation would be, creating `awk` variable which has value of shell variable `$1` in it and in `BEGIN` section setting `FS` as `,` and `OFS` as `|`. In main program checking if 3rd column is matching findit then re-assigning 1st field to itself to apply `OFS` basically to it and printing `FNR` followed by current line value.